# Predicting probabilities of binary event when we can train on probabilities

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, forecasting

I have the probabilities of a sequence of independent binary events Yi occurring. I also have data Xi associated with each Yi. I want to use this to train a model that can predict the probabilities of future events Y occurring given my data X.

Would it still make sense to treat this like an ordinary linear regression problem where I regress my probabilities on my data X? Alternatively, is there a better model that would better suit my problem.

Comment: Would you please post a scatterplot of the data, or add the data to your post?

Comment: it is strange to observe probabilities directly. are you sure that you're not just observing the binary outcomes?

Comment: Any objections, anyone, to using a logistic regression?

Comment: It's difficult to add the data bc. the file is ~1gb and there are ~100+ covariates. Also it's financial data so often times the market price at close can be directly translated to a probability of the binary outcome occuring. I don't know how to use a logistic regression in this instance because the canonincal function of logistic regression is a binomical correct so logistic regression would only work on binary classification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you regress your probabilities against your predictor as you suggest, you may find that your fitted model predicts outside of the $[0,1]$ interval for some values of the predictor $X_i$, which makes interpreting your model awkward.

You could alternatively logit-transform the probabilities, regress these transformed probabilities against your predictor, and then expit-transform your linear predictor to get predictions on the probability scale.

Comment: Isn’t your suggestion a logistic regression?

Comment: Depends on your interpretation of logistic regression I guess. I usually use the term 'logistic regression' as short hand for a generalized linear model when the probability distribution is Binomial and the link function is the logistic link. That's not what this is, since the outcome that the OP is modeling is a continuous variable distributed between 0 and 1. On the other hand, you are right: this is a regression that involves a logistic transformation of the outcome.

Comment: Ah, but a logistic regression is predicting the expected value of the binomial distribution, which could be any value between 0 and 1. I have to give more thought to what kind of loss function would be appropriate, though.

Comment: I would still maintain that it would be at best confusing and at worst wrong to call what I am suggesting a 'logistic regression'. There are two key differences: the nature of the observed data (the OP has continuous values between 0 and 1; a traditional logistic regression has discrete values taking on 0 or 1 only) and the source of variation in the model (the variation in the model that I am proposing would essentially be measurement error in the probabilities; the variation in a traditional logistic regression is the natural binomial variation).